# Como impedir que o método List.size() execute o lazyload com Hibernate e JPA

Tags: java, jpa-2.0

Quando eu faço uma consulta no banco e é retornado um objeto, nesse objeto tem uma coleção, que por padrão é Lazyload, se eu fizer `object.getColecao().size()` ai é executado o lazyload para trazer os registros, se a sessão ou o entitymanager tiver sido fechado, claro que vai acontecer o LazyLoadException.

**Minha pergunta é**, teria como depois que eu receber o objeto da consulta, mesmo que eu faça  `object.getColecao.size()` ele não executar o lazy load?

O problema é que eu faço a consulta e preciso serializar o objeto para JSON, porém, os principais frameworks de processamento de JSON como o Jackson e Gson eles executam implicitamente o `size()` para coleções, dessa forma acontece o LazyLoadException.

Eu não posso configurar os frameworks para ignorar as litas porque se as listas não forem null terá que serializar, ou seja, se for nulo, não serializa, caso contrário serialize. A configuração para não serializar nulos desses dois funciona mas não para listas, mesmo assim eles executam o `size()` para verificar se tem conteúdo, portanto a solução que eu vejo é não executar o lazy load ao chamar método `size()`.

Eu já tentei clonar os objetos usando o SpringBeansUtil, mas mesmo assim ao executar o `size()` é feito uma tentativa de lazyload.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Solução ignorando o atributo ao serializar

Após ver o comentário e entender melhor o problema, penso que a solução seja solicitar à biblioteca Json que ignore os atributos com as coleções na serialização apenas quando for necessário, já que você mencionou que em algumas situações você vai querer incluir as coleções.

### Solução com Gson

Baseado [nesta questão do SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802887/gson-how-to-exclude-specific-fields-from-serialization-without-annotations), há duas formas de excluir determinados campos.

A primeira é anotar os campos que *sempre* serão serializados com a anotação `@Expose`. Quando for necessário serializar todos os campos, utiliza-se a biblioteca normalmente, mas se quisermos serializar apenas os campos com a anotação, podemos fazer assim:

```java
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();
```

A segunda maneira é através da implementação de um `ExclusionStrategy`. Veja um exemplo:

```java
public class ClienteExclusionStrategy implements ExclusionStrategy {

    public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> arg0) {
        return false;
    }

    public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
        return f.getDeclaringClass() == Cliente.class
            && (f.getName().equals("enderecos")) || f.getName().equals("contatos"));
    }

}
```

Então, quando quiser ignorar os endereços e contatos, faça assim:

```java
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setExclusionStrategies(new ClienteExclusionStrategy()).create();
```

### Solução com Jackson

Para sobrescrever o comportamento original de uma classe no momento da serialização você pode usar os [Mixins](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonMixInAnnotations) do Jackson. Trata-se de uma classe abstrata onde você define o comportamento que deseja sem alterar a classe original.

Veja o exemplo:

```java
abstract class ClienteMixIn {
     @JsonIgnore List<Contato> getContatos();
     @JsonIgnore List<Endereco> getEnderecos();
}
```

E, finalmente, adicione o mixin na serialização quando necessário:

```java
objectMapper.getSerializationConfig().addMixInAnnotations(Cliente.class, ClienteMixIn.class);
```

## Solução recuperando os dados do relacionamento

Se entendi bem você quer executar o `size()` sem executar as queries em modo *lazy*. Isso simplesmente não é possível, afinal como o Hibernate poderia saber quantos registros o `join` irá retornar?

Continuando nesse raciocínio, para saber se há itens na coleção e usá-los quando necessário você sempre terá que consultar os itens da coleção.

Uma das soluções para forçar a leitura da coleção enquanto o EntityManager está aberto, mesmo que o relacionamento da entidade esteja configurado em modo *lazy*, é usar um *join fetch*.

O *join fetch* geralmente é usado para melhorar o desempenho quando sabemos antecipadamente que precisaremos acessar esse relacionamento. Internamente, o Hibernate irá trazer os dados da entidade principal e realizar um `OUTER JOIN` nativo no banco de dados para trazer o registros da coleção. Para maiores detalhes, consulte a documentação sobre as diferentes estratégias de otimização [aqui](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/manual/en-US/html/performance.html#performance-fetching).

Um exemplo disso usando Criteria é:

```java
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Entidade> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Entidade.class);
Root<Entidade> root = criteriaQuery.from(Entidade.class);
root.fetch("colecao", JoinType.LEFT); // força um `LEFT OUTER JOIN` nativo
```

Com o código acima, os itens da coleção serão carregados imediatamente e não serão necessárias queries adicionais, ou seja, nada de `LazyLoadException` e apenas uma chamada ao banco.

---

Alternativamente, outra forma de inicializar uma coleção forçadamente quando encessário é utilizar o método estático [`Hibernate.initialize()`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/Hibernate.html#initialize%28java.lang.Object%29).

Este método força o *proxy* da coleção carregar tudo o que é necessário para executar quando o EntityManager for fechado.

Veja um exemplo:

```java
Hibernate.initialize(object.getColecao());
```

## Solução desencapsulando a entidade do *proxy*

O hibernate cria uma classe *proxy* para interceptar as chamadas a atributos *lazy*. Uma outra ideia seria obter a entidade original, sem proxy, pois nesse caso não teríamos o problema de `LazyLoadingException`.

Encontrei [duas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216547/converting-hibernate-proxy-to-real-object) [questões](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11228838/how-to-unproxy-a-hibernate-object) do SOEN com códigos que se propõe a fazer isso. Veja um deles:

```java
public static <T> T initializeAndUnproxy(T entity) {
    if (entity == null) {
        throw new 
           NullPointerException("Entity passed for initialization is null");
    }

    Hibernate.initialize(entity);
    if (entity instanceof HibernateProxy) {
        entity = (T) ((HibernateProxy) entity).getHibernateLazyInitializer()
                .getImplementation();
    }
    return entity;
}
```

Com solução não seria necessário modificar a geração de Json. Basta aplicá-la logo após fazer o *detach* da entidade.

Comment: O problema é que eu não quero que seja realizado o lazy, eu preciso trazer uma lista de clientes, por exemplo, 200 clientes, cada objeto cliente tem duas listas, Contatos e Endereços e eu não quero trazer nem contatos nem endereços mesmo usando o JOIN para otimizar. Blz, quando eu tento converter para JSON essa lista ai é executado o size() pelos processados JSON(Jackson e Gson), no Hibernate 4 eu posso usar isso <prop key="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans">false</prop> ai ele executa normal, só que faz um monte de select no banco, eu só quero trazer a lista simples de clientes sem lazy.

Comment: Sei não, estou pensando serialmente em usar o MentaBean, a gente tem mais controle, já perdi tempo demais com o JPA/Hibernate, não uso anotações que polui demais o código, estou usando os orm.xml mesmo fica tudo separadinho e mais organizado, meus pojos ficam limpos, eu queri muito utilizar o JPA mas já tou há dois 2 direto com esse problema, Já tente getEntityManager().detach(entity); mas não tem jeito, o objeto não é "desconectado" e quando eu chamo o size() é tentando o lazy, estou pensando em fazer manualmente via Reflection uma rotina que copia um objeto para um novo sem estar vinculado..

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues *Acho* que entendi melhor sua situação. Editei a pergunta com o que acredito ser uma solução melhor para o seu caso.

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues E tenha certeza que eu entendo sua frustração com o JPA, certamente é prometida muita facilidade, mas na verdade você acaba tendo que "escovar os bits" para entender como tudo funciona e conseguir o que quer. Não conheço esse MentaBEan (vou pesquisar sobre isso amanhã), mas pense que cada tecnologia tem sua curva de aprendizado e suas nuances que nos "pegam" de vez em quando.

Comment: Quanto as soluções com o jackson e Gson eu já tentei, mas não dá certo, vou explicar, com anotações eu SEMPRE vou dizer que determinado atributo não será serializado, as vezes preciso serializar as listas e as vezes não, não já lazyload entre client e servidor pois é uma aplicação RESTFull, a única comunicação é em JSON. Quanto a solução com Gson usanod ExclusionStrategy eu já fiz e funcionou, porém cai na mesma, determinadas vezes eu preciso serializar ou não, desse jeito eu teria que criar um toJSonWihoutList e toJson, foi o mais próximo que conseguir...

Comment: Seria tão simples se eu tivesse a opção de não querer o lazyLoad, pronto, estaria tudo resolvido, vou ficar tentando aqui e qualquer solução eu posto para ajudar o próximo, cara, muito obrigado pela atenção, obrigado mesmo!

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues Eu entendi que às vezes você quer serializar e outras não, mas não entendo a dificuldade em fazer, por exemplo, um condicional para serializar ou não os atributos dependendo do critério que você quer usando um dos métodos propostos na primeira parte da pergunta. Talvez você esteja misturando um pouco as coisas.

Comment: É,vou ter que fazer dessa forma mesmo, uma condicional, só temo que essa condicional depois vá aumentando...rsrsrs Valew obrigado pelas respostas!

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues Infelizmente às vezes nossos caso de uso parece que sempre são exceções às implementação padrão. Agora de manhã pensei em uma outra abordagem. Dá uma olhada no último tópico que acrescentei à resposta. Sinceramente nunca fiz isso, mas se puder tentar dê um *feedback*.

Comment: desculpe pela demora em responder, fui tentar agora, achei que ia da certo, é exatamente isso que eu preciso, unproxy as entities, porém, não entra de jeito nenhum na condição 'if (entity instanceof HibernateProxy)' eu já enviei a entidade que contém a coleção bem como a coleção em si, que depois que é retornado muda o tipo de List para PersistenceBag, eu realmente achei que ia funcionar. Engraçado, se eu setar manualmente null as listas ai funciona, porém, se eu usar reflection setando null nao funciona, permanece com PersistenceBag o tipo do atributo

Comment: Obs: Eu uso o JPA+Hibernate e não o hibernate puro